# To pass a string containing commas as a IN parameter to mysql stored routines

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to pass a string with commas as an IN parameter to mysql stored procedure. Example:

> string to be passed say **var** = ' Hello,World '

to procedure called insert_data with one IN parameter and one OUT parameter like

```
call( var, @output);
```

When I try to insert data like it I get following error:
**#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1** 
Please guide me how I can go forward with this issue. Am new in using stored routines.Please explain with an example.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to embed it in the string directly or use `find_in_set()`.

Comment: I did not get your point, can you explain with an example